# Directive with default data

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a directive that has `ng-repeat` in its template, and that ng-repeat should either use something set in an attribute, or if attribute not present use "default array"

something like this:

```
app.directive 'myDir',->
  template:'<div> <h1 ng-repeat="d in data"> {{d}} </h1> </div>'
  scope:
     data:"="
  link: (scope, element, attrs)->
    unless attrs.data?
      $scope.data = [1..10]
```

except that doesn't really work, throwing "Non-Assignable Expression" error.

[jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/qapupa/3/)

How do I make it work?

I could probably try using $parse but then I'm gonna have to re-compile the directive? What I want seems to be trivial, shouldn't be too difficult to make it work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `$compile` [documentation for `"="`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception. You can avoid this behavior using =? or =?attr in order to flag the property as optional.

You should set your scope to:

```
scope: {
   data: "=?"
}
```

**OFF TOPIC:** You can also cheaply define a default value right in the template:

```
template: '<div> <h1 ng-repeat="d in (data || [1, 2, 3])"> {{d}} </h1> </div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it doing this:

```
app.directive 'myDir',($parse)->
  restrict:'E'
  template:'<div> <h1 ng-repeat="d in data.headers"> {{d}} </h1> </div>'
  link: (scope, element, attrs)->
    scope.data = {}
    if attrs.headers?
      scope.data.headers = $parse(attrs.headers)(scope)
    else  
      scope.data.headers = [1..10]
```

But `New Dev`'s solution is a lot better

Comment: But then you will lose the 2-way bound-ness (if there is such a word) and you'll need to do something like `attrs.$observe("headers")`...